# How to INSERT data using CREATE VIEW object with multiple tables using INSTEAD OF trigger in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Based on feedback from an stackoverflow user I researched docs.oracle.com about INSTEAD OF tirggers, but I still can't get this right. The view creates fine, but the INSTEAD OF trigger doesn't. Moreover, I don't understand how to set 'n' for multiple inputs. After I execute the code there is no indication of any error or if it worked. I loose the SQL> prompt and can't do anything, ending up having to restart the environment.

Here is what I came up with based off the example from Oracle:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cust_order AS
  2   SELECT book_customer.customerid, lastname, state, book_order.orderid, orderdate
  3    FROM book_customer
  4      JOIN book_order ON book_order.customerid = book_customer.customerid
  5  ;

View created.

SQL> 
SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cust_order_insert
  2   INSTEAD OF INSERT ON cust_order
  3    REFERENCING NEW AS n
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  
  6  DECLARE
  7   rowcnt number;
  8  
  9  BEGIN
 10   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowcnt
 11    FROM book_customer
 12     WHERE book_customer.customerid = :n.book_customer.customerid;
 13      IF rowcnt = 0 THEN
 14       INSERT INTO book_customer(customerid, lastname, state)
 15        VALUES (:n.book_customer.customerid, :n.lastname, :n.state);
 16         ELSE
 17         UPDATE book_customer SET book_customer.customerid = :n.customerid
 18          WHERE book_customer.customerid = :n.customerid;
 19       END IF;
 20       
 21   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowcnt
 22    FROM book_order
 23     WHERE book_order.orderid = :n.orderid;
 24      IF rowcnt = 0 THEN
 25       INSERT INTO book_order(orderid, orderdate)
 26        VALUES (:n.book_order.orderid, :n.orderdate);
 27         ELSE
 28         UPDATE book_order SET book_order.orderid = :n.orderid
 29          WHERE book_order.orderdate = :n.orderdate;
 30       END IF;
 31  END;
 32  
 33  
 34  
 35  
 36  --SQL> prompt won't come back.
 37  
 38  
 39  
 40
```

Here are the table descriptions:

```
SQL> desc cust_order;
 Name                                                              Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------
 CUSTOMERID                                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 LASTNAME                                                                   VARCHAR2(10)
 STATE                                                                      VARCHAR2(2)
 ORDERID                                                           NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ORDERDATE                                                                  DATE
```

Definitions:

```
Create table Book_customer
(CustomerID  NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT PK_BOOKCUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY,
LastName VARCHAR2(10),
FirstName VARCHAR2(10),
Address VARCHAR2(20),
City VARCHAR2(20),
State VARCHAR2(2),
Zip VARCHAR2(5),
Referred NUMBER(4));

Create Table Book_order
(OrderID NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT PK_BOOKORDER_ORDERID PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerID NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT FK_BookOrder_BookCustomer REFERENCES Book_Customer (CustomerID),
OrderDate DATE,
ShipDate DATE,
ShipStreet VARCHAR2(20),
ShipCity VARCHAR2(20),
ShipState VARCHAR2(2),
ShipZip VARCHAR2(5));
```

Any ideas or constructive criticism is appreciated.

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01779_cannot_modify_a_column_which_maps_to_a_non_keypreserved_table.htm  I don't think you can do this.

Comment: Can you post the definitions of the two base tables?  Is this a homework assignment?  Is creating an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view an option?

Comment: The table definitions should also include primary keys, foreign keys, and unique constraints.  Otherwise, we have no idea whether the view can be made key-preserved.  Ideally, you'd post the DDL to create the tables so that we could create them on our systems to test our answers.  Is an `INSSTEAD OF` trigger an option?

Comment: Is an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view an option?

Comment: Yes, an INSTEAD OF trigger can be used. I researched it based off the links that Andrew left, but I still can't get it to work. Unfortunately, I don't have the data dictionary, but I posted the .sql file which is identical to data dictionary information. Any ideas?

Comment: If the `SQL>` prompt doesn't come back, try typing `/` on a line to itself.  The `/` is necessary to tell SQL*Plus that the PL/SQL code in the trigger has ended - SQL*Plus can't tell otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on 3rd party books as it's all described in the Oracle docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#i1025919 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#ADMIN11782

Pay close attention to what **Key-Preserved Tables** mean. In your case, assuming that Book_Customer.Customer is a primary/unique key, you should be able to insert into Book_Customer, but not Cust_Order

Comment: Hello Andrew, I researched the INSTEAD OF trigger, but after many attempts can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess u have not ended the PL/SQL block properly. Just use a '/' at the end. And you can also include DML on both tables under same IF-ELSE block.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cust_order_insert
  2   INSTEAD OF INSERT ON cust_order
  3    REFERENCING NEW AS n
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  
  6  DECLARE
  7   rowcnt number;
  8  
  9  BEGIN
 10   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowcnt
 11    FROM book_customer
 12     WHERE book_customer.customerid = :n.book_customer.customerid;
 13      IF rowcnt = 0 THEN
 14       INSERT INTO book_customer(customerid, lastname, state)
 15        VALUES (:n.book_customer.customerid, :n.lastname, :n.state);
 16       INSERT INTO book_order(orderid, orderdate)
 17        VALUES (:n.book_order.orderid, :n.orderdate);
 18         ELSE
 19         UPDATE book_customer SET book_customer.customerid = :n.customerid
 20          WHERE book_customer.customerid = :n.customerid;
 21         UPDATE book_order SET book_order.orderid = :n.orderid
 22          WHERE book_order.orderdate = :n.orderdate;
 23       END IF;
 24  END;
 25 /
```